# How to add/remove modifier to/from a statement?

Tags: typescript, modifier, typescript-compiler-api

I am using the TypeScript compiler API to transform TypeScript code, but one thing I haven't quite figured out is adding/removing modifiers in a generic way. The closest I've gotten is this

```
function removeDeclareModifier(s) {
    let modifiers;
    // Remove declare modifiers
    if (s.modifiers) {
        modifiers = s.modifiers.filter(m => m.kind !== ts.SyntaxKind.DeclareKeyword);
    } else {
        return s;
    }

    if (ts.isVariableStatement(s)) {
        return ts.updateVariableStatement(s, modifiers, s.declarationList);
    } else if (ts.isTypeAliasDeclaration(s)) {
        return ts.updateTypeAliasDeclaration(s, s.decorators, modifiers, s.name, s.typeParameters, s.type);
    } else if (ts.isInterfaceDeclaration(s)) {
        return ts.updateInterfaceDeclaration(s, s.decorators, modifiers, s.name, s.typeParameters, s.heritageClauses, s.members);
    } else if (ts.isEnumDeclaration(s)) {
        return ts.updateEnumDeclaration(s, s.decorators, modifiers, s.name, s.members);
    } else if (ts.isClassDeclaration(s)) {
        return ts.updateClassDeclaration(s, s.decorators, modifiers, s.name, s.typeParameters, s.heritageClauses, s.members);
    } else if (ts.isFunctionDeclaration(s)) {
        return ts.updateFunctionDeclaration(s, s.decorators, modifiers, s.asteriskToken, s.name, s.typeParameters, s.parameters, s.type, s.body);
    }
    return s;
}
```

but this seems really verbose, is probably missing a ton of cases and is very prone to breaking when one of the signatures change.
I've found another answer where it was suggested to replace the modifiers array, but `s.modifiers` is readonly, so TypeScript won't let me do that.

Is there no better way to just update the modifiers without recreating the entire AST node?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ts.transform

https://github.com/madou/typescript-transformer-handbook#writing-your-first-transformer

```js
  const result = ts.transform<ts.SourceFile>(sourceFiles, [transformer]);

  function transformer<T extends ts.Node>(context: ts.TransformationContext) {
    return (rootNode: T) => {
        function visit(sourceFile: ts.Node): ts.Node {

            return ts.visitEachChild(sourceFile, (node) => converNode(node), context);
        }

        function converNode(node: ts.Node) {

            return ts.visitEachChild(node, visitChilds, context);

            function visitChilds(child: ts.Node): ts.Node | undefined {
                if (child.kind == ts.SyntaxKind.ExportKeyword) return undefined;
                if (child.kind == ts.SyntaxKind.AsyncKeyword) return undefined;

                return ts.visitEachChild(child, visitChilds, context);
            }

         
        }

        return ts.visitNode(rootNode, visit);
    };
}
```